# Multiple pie-charts in the same chart with HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart

I'm trying to draw multiple pie-charts in the same chart with `HighCharts`.

[**`JSFIDDLE DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/Labsu6kk/)

I have enabled the **legend** for each pie-chart. Now **two legends** for the 2 charts are shown at the bottom (*notice that 2 items for each entry are visible in the legend*). When I click on an item of the **legend** it shows/hides a piece in one pie-chart...

But I want to achieve either of followings,

1. I want to have a **single legend** for both charts so that relevant piece of both pie-charts disappears/appears when I click on an item of the **legend**.
2. I want to **show only one legend** and disable it so that clicking doesn't hide/show pieces of pie-charts.

Anybody knows a way to achieve either?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Check if this helps http://jsfiddle.net/TV8f4/

Comment: Thanks @MANOJGOPI . But this doesn't help to achieve what I want... When I click an item in the legend it hides/shows bars in `Delhi HO` and `Regional Offices` at the same time. What I want is to do is something like that with multiple pie carts..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have added the below code to detect the legend item clicked.

```
function(chart) {
        $(chart.series[0].data).each(function(i, e) {
            e.legendItem.on('click', function(event) {
                var legendItem=e.name;

                event.stopPropagation();

                $(chart.series).each(function(j,f){
                       $(this.data).each(function(k,z){
                           if(z.name==legendItem)
                           {
                               if(z.visible)
                               {
                                   z.setVisible(false);
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   z.setVisible(true);
                               }
                           }
                       });
                });

            });
        });
    }
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnj39ume/)

Comment: Can you share any documentation you used for this?

Comment: Using `e.legendGroup` instead of `e.legendItem` seems to be better. Otherwise this doesn't work when I click on the color symbol instead of the label.. http://jsfiddle.net/qnj39ume/1/ Thanks again..

Comment: Is there a way to add individual titles for each chart?